# Updating a label within GridView?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, ajax

I have developed a wall (nested comments) where people can comment on scraps(posts). It includes a thumbs up/down feature, the problem is that when i click on thumbs up the entire page reloads. I want just the label which is displaying number of votes(likes) to be updated and nothing else. How can i do this? This is my attempt which is not working..
ASPX:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/thumbsup.png" height="20px" Width="20px" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'/> &nbsp;
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="Server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="lnklike" eventname="click"  />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.abc((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />

protected void GridViewRowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    var scrapId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "like":

            string chklike = "select likestatus from tbl_like where fromid='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and scrapid='" + scrapId + "'";
            int a = dbo.GetLikesMethod(chklike);
            string chkthumbsdown = "select thumbsdownstatus from tbl_like where fromid='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and scrapid='" + scrapId + "'";
            int b = dbo.GetLikesMethod(chkthumbsdown);

            if (a == 0 && b == 0)
            {
                string sendlike = "insert into tbl_like (ScrapId,FromId,LikeStatus) values('" + scrapId + "','" + Session["UserId"] + "',1)";
                dbo.insert(sendlike);
                //abc(scrapId);
                GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
            }
            else if (a != 0)
            {

                Response.Write("already liked");
            }
            else if (b != 0)
            {
                Response.Write("you can not like something you already downvoted!");
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Method to get number of thumbs up /likes:

```
public static int abc(int scrpid)
{    
     string getlikes = "select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid='" + scrpid + "'";

     dboperation dbo = new dboperation();
     int a = dbo.GetLikesMethod(getlikes);

     return a;
}

public void GetUserScraps(int Id)
{
    string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [tbl_user] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "'";
    //string getlikes = "select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid='"+<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId")%>+"'";
    //  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId")%>

    dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you epxand on what you mean by "not working"?  Whenever you say something is not working, you should always clearly define the expected behavior and the current (incorrect) behavior.

Comment: @jadarnel27 by not working i mean the entire page is reloading when i use the above code (or the entire GridView) I want to refresh only a label which shows the count in that row where user click on Thumbs Up or Like imagebutton

Answer (score 1):

In the grid I would add a link like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="35px">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Link to your javascript method/ajax method">
                                         </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then use a jquery ajax call like [this](http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-post/)

Return your new count in JSON and update the label

Ajax Call

```
function UpdateLikeStatus(imageID, labelid)
{
      $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'Services/MiscService.asmx/UpdateLikeStatus',
                data: "{'imageid':'" + imageID + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //This is the label you want to update with the new count.

                    $('#labelid').html(data.d);

                }
            });
}
```

This would be your Webservice call which can also be used in a WCF service.  To see how to implement a AJAX webservice look [HERE](http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp/Ajax_WebService/index.html)

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string UpdateLikeStatus(string imageid)
{
   string returnedData = "";         
   //Make call to stored procedure that does the update
   returnedData = Storedprocedurecall.UpdateLikeStatus(imageid); //Updates the status and returns a count 
     //Now return the new count.
   return returnedData;  

}
```

On the click event of the image or whatever you are using to update the like status.

```
<img src="" id="genericimage" border="0" onclick="UpdateLikeStatus('<%#Eval("imageid") %>', this);" />
```

imageid = the id of the image you are wanting to update the like status

If you still don't understand let me know.

Comment: I have never used Ajax or Json to to do something like this, can please explain a little bit in detail how i am supposed to make that work? I checked out your link and i could not understand it, how am i supped to implement that code in this case?